# Javascript use split on date range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a date range from some API (not in my control) which has the following possibilities of date format

```
dd-Mmm-yy
dd-Mmm-yyyy
dd/mm/yy
dd/mm/yyyy
mm/dd/yy
mm/dd/yyyy
yyyy-mm-dd
```

So I get the date range as

```
01-Dec-16-06-Dec-16 (as per dd-Mmm-yy) OR
01/12/16-06/12/16 (as per dd/mm/yy)
```

So hyphen (-) is the from/to date separator which the API uses (not in my control) & I get this single combined value

Now, in my code, I want to get the from & to dates separately.

So I use

```
range.split("-")
```

However, this does not work properly for `01-Dec-16-06-Dec-16`

Not sure what is the best way to account for all the possibilities (considering that the from/to date separator would always be -)

Comment: Hacky solution: count the number of `-` in the string. If 1, split. If 5, split by the 3rd hyphen. Better solution if possible, standardise the date formats in the database, or use another character for the join

Comment: Thx, yes I agree standardising is better..But like I said, this is external API..So I don't have much control..BTW...is there any direct way to split by 3rd hyphen ?

Comment: Write a regex??

Comment: There is some ambiguity on the date options. If it is `01/02/03`, how would you know if the format is `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`?

Comment: So I do have a format specifier separately...It is just that I want to get the complete from/to dates separately

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a case of an ugly API, the only way to do this is by using "hacky" solutions.

1. Use @Rory McCrossan's suggestion: count the number of `-` in the string. If 1, split. If 5, split by the third.
2. Since the API uses the same format of date for both the left side and the right side, the total length of the string will always be ("left side" + "-" + "right side"). You can split the text on the middle character.

   e.g.

   ```
   let date = "01-Dec-16-06-Dec-16";
   let idx = date.length / 2;
   let start = date.substr(0, idx);
   let end = date.substr(idx + 1);
   ```
3. Use regex.

Comment: Could you give an example of splitting by 3rd hyphen ?

Comment: My personal recommendation would be #2, because it's easy to use substring. Splitting on the third hypen would give you the exact same result: you would have to get the index of the third hyphen, which will always be the middle character. There's also a "dirtier" way of splitting everything and counting elements, but that's just bad code so I won't show an example. I've edited my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

From the formats provided, it looks like the from and to dates will always be the same length split by `-`. In that case, just do this:

```
var len = (yourDateRange.length - 1) / 2
var dateFrom = yourDateRange.substring(0, len)
var dateTo = yourDateRange.substring(len + 1)
```

If you have any format where the length is variable (Such as full name for month), this obviously won't work

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but gets the job done.

I used a chained `indexOf` call with the previous call as the `fromIndex` parameter (which is the 2nd parameter of `indexOf`). And seeing as there is either `/` in the string (then split by `-`) or not (then split by 3rd `-`), there was no need for any special checks.

```js
function splitDates(date) {
  // ~ is just a fancy way to turn indexOf into a 
  // boolean-equivalent check (-1 is 0, 0 is 1, etc)
  if (~date.indexOf('/')) {
    return date.split('-');
  } else {
    var idx = date.indexOf('-', 1 + date.indexOf('-', 1 + date.indexOf('-')));
    return [date.slice(0, idx), date.slice(idx + 1)];
  }
}

var dates = ['01-Dec-16-06-Dec-16', '01/12/16-06/12/16'];

dates.forEach((date) => {
  alert(splitDates(date))
});
```

Comment: Multiple `.indexOf()` are unnecessary and the branching is unnecessarily complex, considering all strings will always need to be split exactly at the middle character. [Everything you wrote can be replaced with 3 lines of code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40973697/5996785)

Comment: Sounds better. I was just giving it a go